# dynamic ajax dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to make a notification tab work but do not seem to get it right. The dropdown is working fine but the ajax call to newfriends.php is not working right, when viewed with firebug there are no results to be seen in the dropdown.Quite confusing.
(note the dropdown menu is located in header and can only be displayed if the session is initialised)
here is the ajax used in jquery:

```
function load_notifications(view=''){
   $.ajax({
       url: "notification/new_friends.php",
       method: "POST",
       data:{view:"view"},
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data){

           $(".dropdown-menu").html(data.notification);
if(data.unseen_notification>0){
    $(".badge1").html(data.unseen_notification);
}
    }

   });
        //$(".dynamic-notification").load("notification/pm_n.php");
   // $(".dynamic-notification-f").load("notification/new_friends.php");
};
load_notifications();
$(document).on("click",".count_friend", function(){
    load_notifications('yes');
});
//loads every 2 seconds for chat
setInterval(function(){load_notifications();},2000);
```

here is the new_friends.php content:

```
<?php
include '../includes/dbconfig.inc.php';

if (isset($_POST['view'])) {

if($_POST['view'] !=''){
    $update="update friends set count='1' where friend_one=:session and count='0'";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($update);
    $stmt->bindValue(":session", $_SESSION['uname']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$sql123="select id from friends where friend_two=:sess_uname and count='0'";
    $stmt123=$conn->prepare($sql123);
    $stmt123->bindValue(":sess_uname", $_SESSION['uname']);
    $stmt123->execute();
    $request_count=$stmt123->fetchColumn();
    //$count_friend=$stmt123->rowCount();
    /*$sql_f_count="select *from user where user_id=:session_id and activated='1' limit 1";
    $stmt_f_count=$conn->prepare($sql_f_count);
    $stmt_f_count->bindValue(":session_id", $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt_f_count->execute();
    $user_details=$stmt_f_count->fetchAll();
    $friend_badge=$user_details[0]['friend_count_badge'];*/
    require "notification/friend_request_notification.php";
// $new_friends="<span class='dropdown'><a href='#' data-placement='bottom' class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' title='Friend Requests' data-html='true'><span class='count_friend' style=' height:33px; width:30px;'><span class='badge1 label label-pill'>".$count."</span><img src='img/logo/group-button-white.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></span></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></span>";    
//if($request_count[0]>0){
    //$new_friends="<a href='#' data-placement='bottom' class='btn' data-trigger='focus' title='Friend Requests' data-toggle='popover' data-html='true' data-content='".$friend_requests."'><span class='count_friend' style=' height:33px; width:30px;'><img src='img/logo/group-button-white.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></span><span class='badge'>".$friend_badge."</span></a>";
    /*}else{
     $new_friends="<a href='all_notifications.php'><img src='img/logo/group-button-black.png' style='height:25px; width:27px;' alt='new_friends_alert'></a>";   
    }*/
//echo $new_friends;
//}
    $data=array(
        'notification'=>$friend_requests,
        'unseen_notification' =>$request_count[0][0]
    );
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

and the code for friend requests output:

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
require_once 'includes/dbconfig.inc.php';
$sql = "select * from friends where friend_two=:session and accepted='0' order by friends_date_made asc";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindparam(":session", $_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
$numrows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$friend_requests="";
if ($numrows < 1) {
    $friend_requests = "You do not have any friend requests";
    echo "$friend_requests";
    exit();
} else {
    foreach ($numrows as $i=>$row1 ) {
        $reqid = $row1['friend_id'];
        $user1 = $row1['friend_one'];
        $datemade = $row1['friends_date_made'];
        $datemade1 = strftime("%B %d, %y", strtotime($datemade));
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname=:user1 LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindparam(":user1", $user1);
        $stmt->execute();
        $thumbrow = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $user1avatar = $thumbrow[$i]['avatar'];
        $user1id=$thumbrow[$i]['user_id'];

        if ($user1avatar =="") {
            $user1pic = '<img src="img/avatardefault.png" height="50" style="float:left;" width="50" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';
        }  else {
         $user1pic = '<img src="../user/user/'.$user1id.'/'.$user1avatar.'" height="50" style="float:left;" width="50" alt="'.$user1.'" class="user_pic">';

        }
        $friend_requests .= '<li><div id="'.$reqid.'" float="right" class="friendrequests">
        <a href="home.php?u='.$user1.'">'. $user1pic .'</a>
                <div class="user_info '.$reqid.'" id="'.$reqid.'"><small>' . $datemade1 . '</small>
                 <a href="home.php?u='.$user1.'">'.$user1.'</a> is requesting your friendship<br /><br />
        <button id="'.$reqid.'" name="'.$_SESSION['uname'].'" sess="'.$_SESSION['id'].'" class="accept_btn btn btn-warning">Accept</button><span class="show-spinner"></span> or
        <button id="'.$reqid.'" name="'.$_SESSION['uname'].'" sess="'.$_SESSION['id'].'" class="reject_btn btn btn-warning">Reject</button>
        </div>
        </div><hr></li>';


     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently have `data:{view:"view"}`.
Which means that you are passing string `'view'` in the body of your request.

Change it to something like:

```
function load_notifications(thisview=''){
   var theData = {
      view: thisview
   }
   $.ajax({
       url: "notification/new_friends.php",
       method: "POST",
       data: theData,
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data){
```

Comment: still no luck mate firebug says that it is a internal server error and i checked all the queries carefully too. any more suggestions

Comment: Maybe add `error_reporting( E_ALL );`
Go to the page and see if you get any PHP errors.

Also turn on MySQL errors: `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

(Where `$dbh` is the name of the database)

Comment: i have already set the DB connection like that using PDO still the problem persists.

Comment: Did you get any errors back?
Are you sure the relative paths have been defined properly?

Comment: Try doing some more error checking. Like:

`if (isset($_POST['view'])) {
     $test = $_POST['view']
     print_r($test );
     die;`

See if your post is even getting to the page.

Comment: strange var_dump is not throwing errors should head to ubuntu forums for that i guess

Comment: Are you passing anything as view? If not, maybe assign it something just in case. Maybe PHP doesn't think it is set if the value is null.

Comment: even still var_dump should throw bool(false) if im wrong , but it doesn't seem to be throwing that. will clear that in ububntu forums and catch you

Comment: i cleared the ubuntu issues in reporting errors and after correcting all the errors its still not showing results though the firebug is showing output the dropdown menu is not displaying the results any advice would be of great help